# Custom Button Text on JavaScript Confirm

Tags: javascript, reload, confirm

[Mega](https://mega.co.nz/) has an interesting function running on it which appears to customize the title and button text of a JavaScript `confirm()` box:

[image: Customized confirm box]

How is this achieved, when every resource I'm finding here and elsewhere is telling me it's impossible?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that is not a javascript window, checking..How do you get the confirm to show up?

Comment: I reload the page during a file transfer. I'm pretty sure it is a pure JS window, not a polyfill like jQueryUI's dialog, because it has the operating system's (Ubuntu 10.04) window chrome and button style.

Comment: You can tell, because a standard dialog window will allow you to move it outside the browser window, CSS/HTML dialogs you can not move outside the window.

Comment: is that just the browser?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload:function (){if (downloading || ul_uploading) return l[377];} `. Probably this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Are you suggesting the browser itself is creating the dialogue of its own accord, or are you asking if the dialogue matches the browser style? For what it's worth, the browser is Chromium 25.0 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @Passerby, that does look like it's it, so I thank you! Now to Figure out what that's actually triggering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Passerby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570812/passerby)'s suggestion in the question comments, I did some tests, and it turns out that Chromium's `onbeforeunload` text is customized for a reload as opposed to a navigation or page close. As such, reloading the page caused the event to fire and return the reload confirmation.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eXFnR/

Thanks for the insight!